# Iteration through properties with custom attributes in a class

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, iteration

I've got a class like this with some custom attributes. I'm not sure whether i actually have to implement these.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
    private class IsValue : Attribute { }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
    private class IsRep : Attribute { }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    private class IsConstant : Attribute { }
    public static class Constants
    {
        [IsConstant]
        public static class EulerGamma
        {
            [IsValue]
            public const double Value = 0.5772156649015;
            [IsRep]
            public const string Str = "γ";
        }
        [IsConstant]
        public static class EulerNumber
        {
            [IsValue]
            public const double Value = 2.718281828459;
            [IsRep]
            public const string Str = "e";
        }
        [IsConstant]
        public static class Pi
        {
            [IsValue]
            public const double Value = 3.1415926535898;
            [IsRep]
            public const string Str = "π";
        }
        [IsConstant]
        public static class GoldenRatio
        {
            [IsValue]
            public const double Value = 1.6180339887499;
            [IsRep]
            public const string Str = "φ";
        }
    }
```

Let's say this is in some class "MyMathClass", where I'd like to implement a method like this:
`string ValueOrString(double x)`
This method would return string representation of the constant if the number passed is equal to the constant, else it would return the original number.
So, if i passed exactly 3.1415926535898 this method would give me the string "π".
If is passed for example 2.5315621321 this would return me "2.5315621321" (string).
Would you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class that uses a dictionary:

```
public static class Constants
{
    static Dictionary<double, string> constantNames;

    static Constants()
    {
        Constants.constantNames = new Dictionary<double, string>();

        Constants.constantNames.Add(3.1415926535898, "π");
        Constants.constantNames.Add(2.718281828459, "e");
    }

    public static string ValueOrString(double value)
    {
        if (constantNames.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            return constantNames[value];
        }
        else
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When the function `string ValueOrString(double value)` is called, you can check if the provided value exists in the dictionary. If it exists, you retrieve the name of the constant from it. Otherwise, you return the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks for this idea :-D My constructions were so dumb, actually i just simply implement private static list of these constant names in "MyMath" class :)